# Spring Integration Header Enricher Null check

Tags: spring-integration

I have the below header enricher in my configuration.

```
<int:header-enricher input-channel="" output-channel="" id="" >
    <int:header name="OrderNo" expression="@gateway.exchange(#root).payload"/> 
</int:header-enricher>
```

When the payload is null, I am getting the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: payload must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder.<init>(MessageBuilder.java:56) ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Is there a way to check for null payload from gateway and set some dummy value in header, if payload is null?

```
<int:gateway id="gateway" default-request-channel="defReqChannel" />
<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway request-channel="defReqChannel" data-source="dataSourceDD" expect-single-result="true" is-function="false" stored-procedure-name="SP_GET_CODE">
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="param1" direction="IN" />
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="param2" direction="IN" />
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="param3" direction="INOUT" />    
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="param4" direction="IN" /> 

        <int-jdbc:parameter name="param1" expression="exp1" />
        <int-jdbc:parameter name="param2" expression="exp2" />
        <int-jdbc:parameter name="param3" value="0"/>  
        <int-jdbc:parameter name="param4" value="0"/>
</int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>
```

The stored procedure that I am invoking can return a null value. (param3). The failure happens in those scenarios

Answer (score 0):

Please, share more StackTrace. `payload` **can't** be `null` in the `Message`. The code you show is fully controlled by the Framework.

I think there is a code when you do something like `MessageBuilder.withPayload(null)`.

But that fully isn't a case for config you demonstrate.

**UPDATE**

This is really a bug: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4202.

The workaround is like do not use `expect-single-result="true"` and extract target value from the result `Map` downstream manually.

Comment: Please, find an UPDATE in my answer